# lightning record page on new record layout

Tags: lightning-experience

I have created successfully a lightning record page for a custom object. I can view my newly created record page when I open a record (which is the detail view), but my record page does not opens up when I try to create a new record. When I click on new button, I see the default page layout of the object.

Does the record page only works for detail record view?

Comment: the set of fields is determined in the page layout, not in the record page

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can put a lightning component in a page layout?

Comment: not sure, maybe with using [lightning out](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html)